# 74LS173 output voltage won't go above 3V when it should be HIGH. Any ideas why?

Tags: digital-logic, proteus

I'm seeking a solution to understand why the output voltage of the 74LS173 is not reaching 3V or is not in an undetermined state when the output is expected to be HIGH. What could be the the cause of this issue?

[image]

Comment: Is that an LED shorting the pin to GND? Are you familiar with 74LS family pin characteristics?

Comment: if it's not going higher than your LED forward voltage, add more resistors.

Comment: The output of an LS logic gate (most of them) is spec'd at 400 uA, memory serving. They sink a lot more. But they don't source much current. It's up to you to check the specs, though. I could do it. But I think this is better left as a training exercise.

Comment: `What could be the the cause of this issue?` ... anything that is connected to that pin

Answer (score 2):

The LED isn't allowing the output to go above the LED's forward bias voltage, which, depending on the LED, can be about 1.8 ~ 2.0 for red, 2.1 ~ 2.5 for yellow-green, 3.1 for green, and 3.5V for blue. If you disconnect the LED you will see a normal output voltage.

Also, bear in mind that LS logic doesn't have much source drive capability: it has an output-high current of only 2.6mA. Barely enough to drive an LED, really. Here's the data sheet excerpt with the details; note Ioh and Voh (from [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls173a.pdf)):

[image]

Try adding a series resistor to the LED (220 to 330 ohm.) This might be enough to make the 'LS173 happy, although the LEDs will be dim. Otherwise, add inverting buffers between the 'LS173 and the LEDs and drive the LEDs on the low side where the current is more generous (24mA.)

Answer (score 1):

The specified output High voltage for the 74LS family is 2.7 volts minimum, 3.4 volts typical, so your result is normal, particularly if you are loading the outputs with LEDs.

Comment: `High voltage for the 74LS family is 2.7 V min` Unchecked memory claims the value in [hacktastical's answer](/a/689451/274544): can you state a source for 2.7?

Comment: @greybeard: - I got that value from an old TI databook.  That was for 74LS, 54LS is a bit lower.